# Kerberos auth with Apache/PHP on CentOS7

Tags: apache, authentication, kerberos

I want to configure Kerberos auth with Apache - with no success.
It look that problem with keytab file.

When I run:

```
klist -kte /path/to/website.HTTP.keytab
I get: 
  KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
  12 01/01/1970 02:00:00 HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN
```

Then I run:

```
kinit -k -t /path/to/website.HTTP.keytab HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN
kinit: Client 'HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials
```

Any Idea whats goes wrong?

Comment: Share your keytab creation command, if you still have it...

Comment: Adjusted the ktpass command to more accurately reflect the target environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN** is an incomplete SPN, which seems the most likely reason *kinit* can't find the SPN in the database.  A full SPN, as an example, would look like this:  **HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN.COM**.  To fix, you will need to re-create the keytab using that fully-qualified syntax.  [Example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx):

```
ktpass -out HTTP.keytab -mapUser AD_Account_Name@DOMAIN.COM +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES128-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ HTTP/website.domain@DOMAIN.COM
```